# Groovy question to read xml and base64decode

Tags: groovy

I want to modify the incoming message (As shown in the Modified XML) output.

**Incoming XML**

```
<xml>
<Body>
   <Request>
     <Container>
        <name>test</name>
        <Numbers>
             <sn>//base64encodedstring//</sn>
             <sn>//base64encodedstring//</sn>
             <sn>//base64encodedstring//</sn>
        </Numbers>
     </Container>
  </Request>
</Body>
</xml>
```

**Modified XML**

```
<xml>
<Body>
   <Request>
     <Container>
        <name>test</name>
        <Numbers>
             <sn>//Decodedstring//</sn>
             <sn>//Decodedstring//</sn>
             <sn>//Decodedstring//</sn>
        </Numbers>
     </Container>
  </Request>
</Body>
</xml>
```

As per the answer received: I can create an array of ListOfResults.

```
def listOfResults = new XmlSlurper()
.parseText(xml)
.Body.Request.Container.Numbers.sn
.collect { new String(it.text().decodeBase64()) }
```

I can do the following

```
def data = "<xml><Body><Request><Container><name>test</name><Numbers>"
for (i= 0; i <listOfResults.size(); i++)
{
 data = data +"<sn>" +listOfResults[i] + "</sn>";
} 
data = data + "<Numbers></Container></Request></Body></xml>";
```

Modified data

```
<xml><Body><Request><Container><name>test</name>
 <Numbers>
 <sn>decoded string</sn>
 <sn>decoded string</sn>
 <sn>decoded string</sn>
</Numbers> </Container></Request></Body></xml>
```

Is this the fastest way to do this operation? Is there any other better way?

Comment: If you have tried things, then add the source code and the error you got.  There are also lots of SO questions and documentation on the Groovy homepage about reading XML and decoding b64 with Java.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do (assuming your XML is in a string variable called xml):

```
def listOfResults = new XmlSlurper()
    .parseText(xml)
    .Body.Request.Container.Numbers.sn
    .collect { new String(it.text().decodeBase64()) }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a good source so that I can understand the further explanation about "collect", "it.text()". I have tested and it is creating a list (array) of decoded base 64. Furthermore, is there any easy way to update the decoded string in the XML fields (sn)?